# How to focus next input (if any) on next press

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I actually know how to this but I need a different approach.
So I have text input like:

```
<TextInput returnKeyType='next' 
           ref={ref => this.someName = ref}
           onSubmitEditing={(event) => { this.nextFieldName.focus() }}/>
```

Trick is that I don't want to use specific name for next field but to simply focus next if any to focus.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bit broad your question. If you give more details I might help but for now let me give you an example.

Lets say you have an array of data that you are mapping through and creating a form.

```
const data = [
  {
    type: 'text',
    value: 'name'
  },
  {
    type: 'text',
    value: 'surname'
  },
  {
    type: 'number',
    value: 'age'
  }
];
```

Now lets iterate through data

```
data.map((field, index) => {
  return (
    <TextInput
      type={field.type}
      value={this.state[field.value]}
      ref={(ref) => this.refs[index] = ref}
      onSubmitEditing={() => this.onSubmitEditing(index)}
    />
  );
});
```

Now because we know which field are we on and if another field is exists or not we can focus or submit the form.

```
onSubmitEditing = (index) => {
  if (data.length <= (index + 1)) {
    this.refs[index + 1].focus();
  } else {
    // no input to move 
    // submit form
  }
}
```

Comment: I did all like this. I just used string like: ref={ref => this.refs[item.UniqueName] = ref} and inside onSubmitEditing() handler this.refs[] is empty. Solutions was to add this.refs = []; in constructor.

Comment: Did you initialize `this.refs = {}` in constructor? And also can you try using another name. `this.refs` might not work because React is also using. Try using something like `this.fields={}` and then `(ref) => this.fields[item.UniqueName]=ref`

Comment: @bennygenel I've tried this an my `this.refs` is just returning an empty object && `this.fields` just causes my application to crash when I try to log it, has this changed in later  versions of RN?

Comment: Are you setting the refs?

Comment: Yeah, I am. In my constructor function `this.refs = {}`

Comment: @MikeRodham Are you setting each components ref though? Can you create [mcve] in snack.io or something so I can check?

Comment: @bennygenel Here's a link to the code, https://snack.expo.io/BJFpFiQ7m don't think it'll work directly in expo as I pull all my data from the server. It tells me this.refs is deprecated though?

Comment: @bennygenel even calling the parent ref `this.swiper` causes the app to freeze.

Comment: @MikeRodham I don't know why swiper freezes your app but `this.refs` might be reserved because of the previous string refs implementation of react-native. Can you try it with another variable name like `this.inputRefs` or something.

Comment: @bennygenel `this.inputRefs[nextIndex].focus();`  causes `undefined is not an object` unfortunately. Again console.warn/error will freeze the application. Does it have anything to do with React-Navigation as that's the only thing that freezes. I can still move around the swiper etc. However I cannot navigate back to previous pages.

Comment: @bennygenel I figured it out. As I'm mapping through cards > fields, I'm overwriting previous refs. Is it possible to do this.inputRefs[firstIndex][SecondIndex]?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You just need to modify your reading accordingly. Also side-note don't mutate state directly. Use setState always.

Comment: Yeah this is my first application and I'm just getting to grips with everything. Been learning for about a month.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have 2 textInputs then if you press `next`, this is how the next input will be focused:

```
<TextInput returnKeyType='next' 
       onSubmitEditing={(event) => { this.someName.focus() }}
/>

<TextInput returnKeyType='next' 
       ref={ref => this.someName = ref}
/>
```

Comment: This is what I have my question is how to make it without ref.

Comment: @1110 without ref you can't, because without telling react-native which component to focus, it won't do anything. `ref` provides reference to the component and tells react-native to focus this component.