# How to get focus from one textinput to another textinput?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have created a custom text input, suppose it to be 
Now I want to make user to get focused from one textinput to another. Make it as from

```
let {login,pass}=useRef(null)
<MyTextInput placeholder'login' ref={login} onSubmitEditing={()=>pass.focus()}/> 
<MyTextInput placeholder='password' ref={pass}/>
```

Now i am working with functional components in react native And I have tried adding ref to both of it as above. But I am getting error as cannot cannot read property focus of undefined.

Can anyone help me adding focus with this kind of textinputs?

Comment: Can you try this answer? I think this will answer your question! [Focus Next Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47061937/how-to-focus-next-input-if-any-on-next-press?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks @Veno The answer is with class components. i want to make it work with functional components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple snippet that should work in your case assuming your custom `MyTextInput` supports the same props as `TextInput`

```
export default function App() {
  const useranme = React.useRef(null)
  const password = React.useRef(null)
  return (
    <View>
      <MyTextInput onSubmitEditing={()=>password.current.focus()} ref={useranme} />
      <MyTextInput ref={password} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @SaachiTech, but I am getting error as cannot read property focus of null